# Dynamic table with sticky header and footer in flutter web

Tags: flutter, datatable, datatables, flutter-web, syncfusion

I am working with tables in my flutter web app.Where I have to stick table's header and footer and create table dynamically.I am using syncfusion_flutter_datagrid library.Using this library I am able to stick header and footer but not able to create table dynamically.In syncfusion example the columns and rows are hardcoded.I don't want to hardcode the columns and rows.I want to make it dynamic completlty.Any help would be appreciated in making table dynamic.Below is the sample json I am providing using which table has to be created dynamically.
Thanks!!
Reference:https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_datagrid

Comment: Please provide your dummy json or dynamic collection data set. It helps us to analysis and provide the further details.

Comment: Dummy json:
String jsondata = '''{
        "REPORT_DETAIL": [
            {
                "firstName": "Shiv",
                "lastName": "A",
                "docNo": "0",
                "docDate": "05-Jan-2021",
                "address": "Bangalore",
                "stateName": "35-ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS",
                 "panNumber":"AAAPZ1234C",
                 "adharNumber": "678954321234"
            }
        ]
    }''';

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for contacting Syncfusion support.
Based on the provided information, we suspect that you are trying to add the column at runtime. You can maintain an instance in the type of List, add the columns to this instance and assign this instance to the columns property of SfDataGrid. You can add any column at run time to the instance and call setState() to rebuild the datagrid.

```
   List<GridColumn> _columns;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    employees = getEmployeeData();
    employeeDataSource = EmployeeDataSource(employeeData: employees);
    _columns = _getColumns();
  }
SfDataGrid _buildDataGrid() {
    return SfDataGrid(
        source: employeeDataSource,
        footerFrozenRowsCount: 1,
        columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill,
        columns: _columns);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter DataGrid Demo'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 60,
              ),
         FlatButton( 
      color: Colors.red[100], 
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( 
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(20.0)), 
      ), 
      child: Center( 
        child: Text( 
          'Add Column', 
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), 
        ), 
      ), 
      onPressed: () { 
        setState(() { 
          _columns.add( 
              GridNumericColumn(mappingName: 'salary', headerText: 'Salary')); 
        }); 
      }, 
    ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              FlatButton(
                color: Colors.red[100],
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(20.0)),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Remove Column',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _columns.removeAt(1);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(child: _buildDataGrid())
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

SampleLink:   https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/317477/ze/main424752137

Please provide more details in case we misunderstood your requirement.

Comment: I have edited my post.Table needs to be created dynamically using json data.In future if some more columns are adding then I dont need to hardcode the columns.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Step 1:

I have prepared the dummy json data, if its differ in real time case we have to do some modification in getData() method

```
[
  {
    "REPORT_DETAIL": [
      {
        "firstName": "Shiv",
        "lastName": "A",
        "docNo": "0",
        "docDate": "05-Jan-2021",
        "address": "Bangalore",
        "stateName": "35-ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS",
        "panNumber": "AAAPZ1234C",
        "adharNumber": "678954321234"
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Bala",
        "lastName": "A",
        "docNo": "0",
        "docDate": "05-Jan-2021",
        "address": "Bangalore",
        "stateName": "35-ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS",
        "panNumber": "AAAPZ1234C",
        "adharNumber": "678954321234"
      },
      {
        "firstName": "Deva",
        "lastName": "A",
        "docNo": "0",
        "docDate": "05-Jan-2021",
        "address": "Bangalore",
        "stateName": "35-ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS",
        "panNumber": "AAAPZ1234C",
        "adharNumber": "678954321234"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Step 2:

--> Source required for populating the rows in DataGrid.

```
class EmployeeDataGridSource extends DataGridSource<dynamic> {
  List<dynamic> employeeData = [];

  @override
  List<dynamic> get dataSource => employeeData.map<dynamic>((e) {
        return e.entries.toList();
      }).toList();

  @override
  dynamic getValue(dynamic data, String columnName) {
    return data.firstWhere((e) => e.key == columnName).value;
  }
}
```

Step 3:

---> I have used the local json with provided data, so I used the FutureBuilder. Incase if your fetching directly from the firebase or azure please the SteamBuilder

```
class _EmployeesListState extends State<EmployeesList> {
  EmployeeDataGridSource _employeeDataGridSource;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _employeeDataGridSource = EmployeeDataGridSource();
  }
  
  Future<List<dynamic>> getData() async {
    String responseBody = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/demo_data.json");
    var data = await json.decode(responseBody);
    data = data[0]['REPORT_DETAIL'];
    _employeeDataGridSource.employeeData = [];
    for (final val in data) {
      _employeeDataGridSource.employeeData.add(val);
    }
    return Future<List<dynamic>>.value(data);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Dynamic SfDataGrid'),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
          future: getData(),
          builder: (context, snapShot) {
            if (snapShot.hasError ||
                snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }

            dynamic headerData = snapShot.data[0];
            headerData = headerData.keys.toList();
            return SfDataGrid(
                source: _employeeDataGridSource,
                columns: headerData
                    .map<GridColumn>((e) => GridTextColumn(
                        mappingName: e,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                        headerTextOverflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                        maxLines: 2,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                        headerPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2)))
                    .toList());
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

I have used the dynamic type on code .. you can make then as proper cast to the necessary steps